# Creating on the heap an instance created by value by a factory function

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory

Some APIs offer factory functions to create objects:

```
class C {
  C() {} // private! use `C::make()` to create instances
public:
  static C make() { return C(); }
};
```

Sometimes I need to create an instance `C` on the heap (a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`), but the factory-function above only creates it on the stack.

Is there any way to create an instance `C` on the heap, without creating one on the stack then copying/moving it on the heap using this type of API? What if `C`'s copy and move constructors and assignment operators are deleted?

I think this should be trivial, since with NRVO it's the caller who initializes the space for C in memory... But for some reason it's not trivial at all.

Any C++ version is fine.

Comment: return a `unique_ptr<C>` instead?

Comment: If you are using C++17, there shouldn't be a copy or move using `C* c_ptr = newC(C::make());`

Comment: @AndyG: `C` is defined in a library, not my code.

Comment: If you can't change `C` you could wrap it: `struct C_wrapper { C_wrapper() : instance(C::make()) {} C instance; }; auto foo = std::make_unique<C_wrapper>();`

Comment: @NathanOliver: you're right, I didn't know that. Unfortunately it works with `new`, but not with `std::make_unique`. Should I pass the created pointer to the `std::unique_ptr<C>`'s constructor? Normally that's bad, I wonder if it's the only way in this case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I didn't think of that. Cool solution.

Comment: @Helloer: It's not bad to construct a unique_ptr with a raw pointer. In fact for a while it was the only way to make a unique pointer

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable work around for this case.  `make_unique` is needed for exception guarantees pre C++17, but if you are using C++17 then `auto c_ptr = std::unique_ptr<C>newC(new C(C::make()));` should do what you need and be 100% safe.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Pardon my ignorance, but I don't recognize what `newC` is. What is this expression?

Comment: @FredLarson It's a typo that I can't fix :(.  its meant to be `C* c_ptr = new C(C::make());` and `auto c_ptr = std::unique_ptr<C>(new C(C::make()));`.  That'll teach me to copy pasta

Comment: @NathanOliver: Ah, so it wasn't my ignorance, then? Thank you!

Comment: Note: There is no such concept as heap and stack in C++ and it is non-productive to think that way (as shown by this question). This returns an object by value. It can be stored anywhere (the object it is stored in can just as easily be heap* (dynamic storage duration) or stack* (automatic storage duration). If the copy move constructors/assignment are deleted then this factory method is just not going to work (so that is a red herring) in the first place.

Comment: Why can not just return the `C` object from the function? It has to be movable or copyable. The designer of `C` obviously knows that the object is being returned by value and will have made it return efficiently. So I don't see any need to use a smart pointer given the current information we have. The need to have it dynamically allocated has not been established yet.

Answer (score -2):

This basic trick will ensure that everything allocated on the stack is also allocated on the heap, by forcing the stack to be a subset of the heap.

```
int main() {
 void* heap_pointer = malloc(9999999);
 __asm {
  lea esp, [heap_pointer + 9999999]
 }
 ... 
}
```

Comment: I need the instance of `C` on the heap because I want it to remain alive after I return from my function. Changing the base address of the stack wouldn't help with this.

Comment: @Helloer Store the C in an object that is dynamically created.

Comment: @Helloer Put `volatile char __unused[100000];` in the beginning of your function.